# Disabling the listening to rabbit queues from spring application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I want to create an application-development.properties file in spring to define a dev environment. In this environment want to disable the listening to the rabbit queues because I don't want to interfere with the staging queues while debugging etc.

Problem is - I can't find a property that controls this. No "active" property or "enabled" property or anything..

These are the properties I found in the [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

```
# RABBIT (RabbitProperties)
spring.rabbitmq.addresses= # connection addresses (e.g. myhost:9999,otherhost:1111)
spring.rabbitmq.dynamic=true # create an AmqpAdmin bean
spring.rabbitmq.host= # connection host
spring.rabbitmq.port= # connection port
spring.rabbitmq.password= # login password
spring.rabbitmq.requested-heartbeat= # requested heartbeat timeout, in seconds; zero for none
spring.rabbitmq.listener.acknowledge-mode= # acknowledge mode of container
spring.rabbitmq.listener.concurrency= # minimum number of consumers
spring.rabbitmq.listener.max-concurrency= # maximum number of consumers
spring.rabbitmq.listener.prefetch= # number of messages to be handled in a single request
spring.rabbitmq.listener.transaction-size= # number of messages to be processed in a transaction
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=false # enable SSL support
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.key-store= # path to the key store that holds the SSL certificate
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.key-store-password= # password used to access the key store
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.trust-store= # trust store that holds SSL certificates
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.trust-store-password= # password used to access the trust store
spring.rabbitmq.username= # login user
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host= # virtual host to use when connecting to the broker
```

I did find a way not to load the amqp-context.xml beans that contain the listener definitions by using [Spring profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) and add `<beans profile="development"> .. </beans>` to the xml but this is much less flexible as I have to define different profiles, and changing what they include involves changing the code.

**EDIT** this is how my amqp-context.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.3.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>application.${env:xxxx}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="${rabbit_host}"
        virtual-host="${rabbit_virtual_host}" username="${rabbit_username}" password="${rabbit_password}" port="${rabbit_port}"/>   

    <!-- Connection Factory -->
    <bean id="rabbitConnFactory"
        class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    </bean>


    <!-- Spring AMQP Template -->
    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="routingKey" value="${my_queue}" />
        <property name="queue" value="${my_queue}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Spring AMQP Admin -->
    <bean id="admin" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin">
        <constructor-arg ref="rabbitConnFactory" />
    </bean>

    <rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" requeue-rejected="false" concurrency="10">
        <rabbit:listener ref="ProcessMessage"
            queue-names="${queue_name}" />
    </rabbit:listener-container> 

    <bean id="ProcessStuff" class="Process" />



</beans>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I can manage the listening to queues directly from the application.properties file? please?

Comment: what does your amqp-context.xml look like?

Comment: @jst I added it to the content of the question

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to waiting for Boot 1.3, you can add your own key to application-development.properties like

```
rabbit.auto-startup=false
```

Then modify your amqp-context.xml like this

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" requeue-rejected="false" concurrency="10" auto-startup=${rabbit.auto-startup}>
```

Comment: Can you help me with related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068307/setting-listener-configuration-dynamically-based-on-environment-in-spring-xml

Answer (score 2):

Good catch! I've created [#3587](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3587) which will be addressed for Spring Boot 1.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.auto-startup=false
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.auto-startup=false
spring.rabbitmq.listener.stream.auto-startup=false
```

Answer (score 0):

This one "`spring.autoconfigure.exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration`" doesn't help me. So I just remove all properties start with `spring.cloud.stream.*` and spring.rabbitmq.addresses. Also add to your logback

```
<logger name="org.springframework.amqp" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.amqp" level="ERROR"/>.
```

Because when you remove the properties, spring output a lot of WARN logs.